# Instantiate controller in another controller in azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

For a simple todo example with Azure App Service,, I have a `TodoUserController` which is a `TableController` and a `FacebookController` which is an `ApiController`.

In the `FacebookController`, I want to get list of users in the `TodoUserController`

*TodoUserController*

```
 public class TodoUserController : TableController<TodoUser>{...}
```

*FacebookController*

```
public class FacebookController : ApiController{
    ....
    TodoUserController ctrl = new TodoUserController();
    var users = ctrl.GetAllTodoUsers();
    ....
}
```

I get `NullException` in instantiating `TodoUsersController`

How do I get the users in `TodoUserController`?

Comment: Just don't do this. Move the important logic into a third location, don't create a controller you don't need.

Comment: I still get `NullException` when I use `var response = await client.GetAsync("path/TodoUser");`

Comment: Did you read David's comment? Let me repeat: *don't do this*. Move the logic into another location, then call the logic there. Controllers are supposed to be the interface between the client's browser and your backend, they're not there for back-end to back-end calls.

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need to resolve this, as others have commented, your shared code for retrieving your list of todo's should be moved elsewhere. Typically into a service and your TodoUserController and your FacebookController can both call that service to get the data they need:

```
public class TodoUserService {
    public IEnumerable<TodoUser> GetAllTodoUsers() {
        Console.WriteLine ("Getting todos...");
        // ...
    }
}

public class TodoUserController : TableController<TodoUser> {
    public IEnumerable<TodoUser> GetAllTodoUsers() {
        TodoUserService todoUserService = new TodoUserService();
        return todoUserService.GetAllTodoUsers();
    }
}


public class FacebookController : ApiController {
    public FacebookStuff GetFacebookStuff() {
        TodoUserService todoUserService = new TodoUserService();
        var users = todoUserService.GetAllTodoUsers();
        // ... other Facebook stuff     
    }
}
```

This achieves what I assume you wanted to do - keep your code DRY by not repeating the logic in both places, and also keeps a Separation of Concerns (SoC). As mason mentions controllers should ideally contain minimal code and mainly handle requests to and from the client.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I try to work with the `DbContext` in `TodoUserService` and I still get `NullReferenceException` when attempting to use `ctx` after  `MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext()`

Comment: Are you getting the exception when you call `await client.GetAsync("path/TodoUser")` ? If so, it could be that your mappings are incorrect. Are you, or were you able to get any data from the `TodoUserController` on it's own before you made the service?

Comment: I've not tried to work with `TodoUserController` on its own. Let me put some dummy data there and try. I always get exception when I call `await clientGetAsync("anypath")`.